# Select first instance only with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am parsing some XML something like this:

```
<root>
    <some_gunk/>
    <dupe_node>
        ...
        stuff I want
        ...
    </dupe_node>
    <bits_and_pieces/>
    <other_gunk/>
    <dupe_node>
        ...
        stuff I don't want
        ...
    </dupe_node>
    <more_gunk/>
</root>
```

An XPath of `'//dupe_node'` will give me two instances of `dupe_node` to play with. I only want to traverse the first. Can I do this with XPath?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
/descendant::dupe_node[1]
```

`//dupe_node[1]` is generally wrong, although it produces an identical result in this particular case. [See docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#path-abbrev):

> The location path //para[1] does not mean the same as the location path /descendant::para[1]. The latter selects the first descendant para element; the former selects all descendant para elements that are the first para children of their parents.

Given the following XML:

```
<foo>
    <bar/>
    <foo>
        <bar/>
    </foo>
</foo>
```

`//bar[1]` will produce two nodes, because both bars are first children of their respective parents.

`/descendant::bar[1]` will give only one node, which is the first of all the bars in the document.

Comment: So how do you write it if you want the first node that is a descendant or self? /descendant::dupe_node[1] excludes self right?

Answer (score 7):

```
//dupe_node[1]
```

XPath counts from 1, not 0 in this case. You can use this tool to try things out in your browser:

http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx?mid=82

Answer (score 4):

//dupe_node[1]