# XPath Get first element of subset

Tags: xpath

I have XML like this:

```
<AAA>
    <BBB aaa="111" bbb="222">
        <CCC/>
        <CCC xxx="555" yyy="666" zzz="777"/>
    </BBB>
    <BBB aaa="999">
        <CCC xxx="qq"/>
        <DDD xxx="ww"/>
        <EEE xxx="oo"/>
    </BBB>
    <BBB>
        <DDD xxx="oo"/>
    </BBB>
</AAA>
```

I want to get first `<CCC>` element. But with XPath expression `//*/CCC[1]` I have got two `<CCC>` elements. Each of them is the first elemet in `<BBB></BBB>` context. How to get first element in subset?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy one-liner XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted element. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select first instance only with XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453191/select-first-instance-only-with-xpath)

Comment: Great question. Actually did a [blog post](http://generalredneck.com/blog/xpath-conditionals-subsets) on this recently!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This one should work for you:

```
(//*/CCC)[1]
```

Answer (score 15):

> I want to get first element. But with
>   XPath expression `//*/CCC[1]` I have
>   got two elements. Each of them is the
>   first elemet in `<BBB></BBB>` context.
>   How to get first element in subset?

**This is a FAQ**:

The `[]` operator has a higher precedence (binds stronger) than the `//` abbreviation.

**Use**:

```
(//CCC)[1]
```

This selects the first (in document order) `CCC` element in the XML document.

Comment: So, what is it that causes that problem?

Comment: @Priti, This is a *rule*, saying that CDATA is only a lexical representation of a (part of) the value of a text node. And this has nothing to do with the current question/answer. If you had got any useful XPath book, you wouldn't be asking such basic questions. Or if you ask this as a proper SO question, then many people would answer promptly.

Comment: @Priti, I explain this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007413/xpath-query-to-get-nth-instance-of-an-element/4008925#4008925

Comment: @Priti, This happens when you have specified `<xsl:output method="xml/>` (which is the default output method). If you specify `<xsl:output method="text"/>` the characters will be unescaped.

Comment: Here is my [`question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657003/need-to-understand-why-cdata-section-is-treated-as-if-the-cdata-and).

Comment: Thanks .. I was waiting for you,hoping that you would add anything more with that. As you approved,I am going to mark it as accepted answer.