# Need to understand - why CDATA section is treated as if the <![CDATA[ and ]]>?

Tags: xpath

I was reading a text book to learn *XPath*. And the below line I found from that book:

> How does XPath handle text in XML CDATA sections? Each character within a CDATA section is treated as character data. In other words, a CDATA section is treated as if the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` were removed and every occurrence of markup like `<` and `&` was replaced by the corresponding character entities like `&lt;` and `&amp;`.

But the book didn't give any examples to explain the above sentences. Can any one help me to understand what the Author tried to say in the below:

> **a CDATA section is treated as if the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` were removed and every occurrence of markup like `<` and `&` was replaced by the corresponding character entities like `&lt;` and `&amp;`.**

Comment: Book's probably badly typeset, and someone ripped out the encoded entities and put in the the rendered equivalents: CDATA means that while within the cdata block, `<` is treated as if it was `&lt;`, and `&` is `&amp;`. e.g. the xml metacharacters lose their "meta-ness".

Comment: Actually it was the question which was badly formatted. :)

Comment: @JensErat thanks for the *edit*. I don't know why that part got hidden :(

Comment: @Priti That happens a lot. Stackoverflow uses Markdown for formatting posts (which I regard superior anyway), but also allows HTML. This leads to lots of missing XML input all the time, as browsers ignore them if they're not HTML...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think of it the other way round - everything between a `<![CDATA[` and the next `]]>` is treated as text, and not subject to the usual decoding of entity references, and `<` signs don't introduce element names.  So

```
<something><![CDATA[<foo>text&more</foo>]]></something>
```

is the same as

```
<something>&lt;foo>text&amp;more&lt;/foo></something>
```

whereas

```
<something><foo>text&more</foo></something>
```

is not well-formed XML (because the `&` is treated as the start of an entity reference but there's no corresponding `;` to end it).

Comment: +1 good explanation and example (although I think the first paragraph may be more confusing than helpful). I guess you're saying that you think of it in terms of the text inside the CDATA not getting parsed; where as the book describes that stuff as being escaped before being parsed. I guess I think of it the same way as you, though the book is right too.