# Select unique set of nodes with XPath?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath

I want to select a set of elements as nodes (the content of `div[@class="Adres"]`):

```
<div class="KolumnaStyl">
  <div class="Nazwa">ABCD</div>
    <div class="Adres">
      12-345 Warszawa
      <br/>
      ul. Krasnobrodzka 5
      <br/>
      Mazowieckie
```

This can be done with:

```
//div[@class="KolumnaStyl"]/div[@class="Adres"]/node()
```

As it happens, there are two identical `div[@class="Adres"]` on the page, which means that `node()` currently selects the content of both of them. I can't, however, call `//div[@class="KolumnaStyl"][1]` - that doesn't select the first occurrence.

How can I select a unique set of nodes if the parent directory exists multiple times?

Comment: *unique* means the first one or what ?

Comment: Arrays start from zero don't they? If you want the first occurrence wouldn't you use a zero? //div[@class="KolumnaStyl"][0] ?

Comment: It means the first appearance of //div[@class="KolumnaStyl"]//div[@class="Adres"]

Comment: @user3334690: In XPath, `position()` starts from 1.

Comment: @choroba I thought that might be the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at "[XPath Get first element of subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621416/xpath-get-first-element-of-subset)".

Basically, [predicates have higher precedence](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html) than the `/` and `//` operators.

So, `(//div[@class="KolumnaStyl"]//(div[@class="Adres"]))[1]` should return your desired result.

Also check out [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths) for more background info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first matched one, then do :

```
(//div[@class="KolumnaStyl"]//div[@class="Adres"])[1]/node()
```

In **XPATH** first means `1`, not `0`.

Here is a sample HTML :

```html
<body>
    <div class="foo">
        <p> 12 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="foo">
        <p> 112 </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

`XPATH` expression:

```xpath
(//div[@class = 'foo'])[1]
```

*output*

```html
<div class="foo">
  <p>12</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The Xpath you provided is invalid?

Comment: @Severin Why so you think ?

Comment: I get "Invalid Xpath". It brakes as soon as I add parenthesis around the div.

Comment: @Severin: The opening parenthesis should be at the very beginning.