# First Element of XPATH

Tags: php, dom, xpath

The question looks like the same as : [XPath Get first element of subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621416/xpath-get-first-element-of-subset) but it's, I think, a bit different.

Here's the following blog:
http://www.mademoiselledeco.com/

I want to get the first picture of each post. For that, I thought of the following xpath query :

```
//div[contains(@class,'type-post status-publish')]//img/@src
```

Following the example of the previous post I mentionned, I also tried:
 `//div[contains(@class,'type-post status-publish')](//img/@src)[1]`

but that says

> Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This `//div[contains(@class,'type-post status-publish')]//img[1]/@src` doesn't work?

Comment: No unfortunately, its seems to take all img element of each post. What I'm trying to do is to get only the first occurence of the img tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I understand, after inspection of the source: each `<img>` is contained in a `<p>`, thus `img[1]` will match all pictures, since they are, in the context of a paragraph, the first image.

In this context, I would rather try getting the first paragraph containing an image:

```
//div[contains(@class,'type-post status-publish')]//p[img][1]/img/@src
```

With this XPath I get 9 `img/@src`.

Answer (score 1):

```
//div[@class='post-content-container']//p[./img][1]/img
```

This is not the best solution but I think it would work.

```
//div[@class='post-content-container']
```

Should get each post

```
//p[./img][1]/img
```

Should get the first paragraph, which contains an image. Then selects the image.

Comment: Glad I could help. I believe @potame answer would do the job aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the duplicate question you've picked isn't that far off. It has an explanation in [one of it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5621660/367456) which sounds pretty legit:

> The `[]` operator has a higher precedence (binds stronger) than the `//` abbreviation.

So the `//img` abbreviation stands in your way. Let's expand it:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::img
```

Adding `[1]` at the end would select each first img child (which is exactly as others have outlined). This is also the reason why there is higher precedence for the predicate here.

The [Abbreviated Syntax section in Xpath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) actually covers this with a note:

> **NOTE:** The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant para element; the former selects all descendant `para` elements that are the first `para` children of their parents.

That is:  you're not looking for the `descendant-or-self` axis and any nodes children therein, but just for the first `img` element in the `descendant` axis:

```
/descendant::img[1]
```

So the xpath expression in full:

```
//div[contains(@class,'type-post status-publish')]/descendant::img[1]/@src
```

Result with your example (10):

```
 src="http://www.mademoiselledeco.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Couleur-FionaLynch-Caroline-St.jpg"
 src="http://www.mademoiselledeco.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2-OF-MO-cascade-lumineuse2-1024x398.jpg"
 src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2e/f7/eb/2ef7eb28dc3e6ac9830cf0f1be7defce.jpg"
 src="http://www.mademoiselledeco.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/couleur-peinture-flamant-vert-trekking.jpg"
 src="http://www.mademoiselledeco.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Lily-of-the-Valley-Designed-by-Marie-Deroudilhe-02.jpg"
 src="http://www.mademoiselledeco.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/shopping-decoration-jaune-bleu-delamaison-1024x866.jpg"
 src="http://www.mademoiselledeco.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/wikao-cheminee-berlin-mademoiselledeco4.jpg"
 src="http://www.mademoiselledeco.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/voeux2015-mademoiselledeco-blog.jpg"
 src="http://www.mademoiselledeco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/suite-novotel-constance-guisset-1.jpg"
 src="http://www.mademoiselledeco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/wish-list-decoration-noel-2014.jpg"
```

I hope this sheds some light.