# XPath to select first element in a dropdown list

Tags: xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

The list in the drop down which i'm working on, is not static. Values in current dropdown are : Lock1, Lock2, Lock3, Lock4.
As these are dynamic values, i want to write my own xpath according to its position in drop down list.
I want to select Lock1.

```
<div class="dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle btn-block" type="button">
        <!-- react-text: 62 -->
        Lock1
        <!-- /react-text -->
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"/>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="m-l-xs m-r-xs">
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" placeholder="search"/>
                <i class="icon icon-search"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-list">
            <li class="active">
                <a title="Lock1">Lock1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a title="Lock2">Lock2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a title="Lock3">Lock3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a title="Lock4">Lock4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Given this input example, what is your requested output? How about a slightly different input?

Comment: I want to select Lock1 with Xpath. @renato vitolo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(//ul[@class='dropdown-list']/li[@class='active']/a)[1]
```

or

```
(//div[@class='dropdown-menu']/ul[@class='dropdown-list']/li[@class='active']/a)[1]
```

References:

[XPath Get first element of subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621416/xpath-get-first-element-of-subset)

[XPath: Select first element with a specific attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006283/xpath-select-first-element-with-a-specific-attribute)

Comment: When I use your xpaths, I receive an exception: Unable to locate element. However I have edited your given path to: (//ul[@class='dropdown-list']/li[1])[1] and this xpath works.. Thanks for help

Comment: Probably the exception is raised because none of the `li` elements has `class="active"`  in your application.

Answer (score 0):

`//ul/li[1]` returns `Lock1`, is that what you're after?

You might want to be a bit more specific with `ul` or `li` classes, but I'll leave that up to you.

PS: Next time you ask somebody to write an XPath expression for you, please make sure your input is valid (you're missing a closing `</div>`).

Comment: I have edited the code.. But, //ul/li[1] did not select Lock1

Comment: What code? I literally posted your example into an online XPath testing tool, fixed the markup and wrote that expression to test it.