# Python with Selenium || how to select first option in listbox?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In a constantly updated listbox, I have to select the first tile each time.

[image]

This list will be constantly updated and I have to regularly click on the first option.

```
 WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"dual-listbox__available"))).click()
```

I can't get a response from your code.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you can get the first element by a CssSelector. Find the google chrome extension SelectorsHub so you can get the CssSelector easily which will solve your problem.

Comment: Not working. I select that item and take it elsewhere, and when the list is refreshed, it doesn't work when I want to buy the first item again.

Comment: Try these references: 
[Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953198/xpath-to-select-first-element-in-a-dropdown-list) 
[Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006283/how-to-select-the-first-element-with-a-specific-attribute-using-xpath)