# Strip out first IMG elements in an HTML block

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP app that grabs HTML from third party sources, the HTML may come with one or more IMG elements in it. I want to grab the first IMG instance in it's entirety, but am not sure how to go about that.

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XPath to parse the html, and pull out the data you want that way. It's a little more involved than string position checking, but has the advantage of being a bit more robust should you decide that you want something more specific (`src` and `alt` of first `img` tag, for example).

First you load the html string in to a DOMDocument, which is then loaded in to XPath.

```
// Load html in to DOMDocument, set up XPath
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
```

We want the first `img` that occurs on the page, so use the selector `/descendant::img[1]`. N.B, this is not the same as `//img[1]`, though that may often give similar results. There's a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/453902/2287) on the difference between the two.

```
$matches = $xpath->evaluate("/descendant::img[1]");
```

A downside of using XPath is that it doesn't make it easy to say "give me back the full string that was matched for that `img` tag", so we can put together a simple function that'll iterate over the matched node's attributes and re-build an `img` tag.

```
$tag = "<img ";
foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
    $vals[] = $attr->name . '="' . $attr->value . '"';
}
$tag .= implode(" ", $vals) . " />";
```

Putting it all together we get something like:

```
<?php
// Example html
$html = '<html><body>'
    . ' <img src="/images/my-image.png" alt="My image" width="100" height="100" />'
    . 'Some text here <img src="do-not-want-second.jpg" alt="No thanks" />';

// Load html in to DOMDocument, set up XPath
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Get the first img in the doc
// N.B. Not the same as "//img[1]" - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/453902/2287
$matches = $xpath->evaluate("/descendant::img[1]");
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo buildImgTag($match);
}

/**
 * Build an img tag given it's matched node
 *
 * @param DOMElement $node Img node
 *
 * @return Rebuilt img tag
 */
function buildImgTag($node) {
    $tag = "<img ";
    $vals = array();
    foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
        $vals[] = $attr->name . '="' . $attr->value . '"';
    }
    $tag .= implode(" ", $vals) . " />";

    return $tag;
}
```

```

So overall it's a slightly more complex approach than doing a `strpos` or regex on the html, but should provide you with more flexibility should you decide to do anything with the `img` tag, like pulling out a specific attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Example below would work if you assume that the HTML is a valid HTML however we **cannot** assume that! If you are 100% sure that it would be a valid HTML then go ahead and use it, if not I would suggest you to use **BETTER WAY** as shown below.

```
$html = '<br />First<img src="path/abc.jpg" />Next<img src="path/cde.jpg" />';

$start = stripos($html, '<img');
$extracted = substr($html, $start);
$end = stripos($extracted, '>');

echo substr($html, $start, $end+1);
```

This code will give you: `<img src="path/abc.jpg" />`

1. Find the first occurrence of `<img` with case-insensitive function
   [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)
2. Chop actual data starting from the first occurence point.
3. Find the first occurrence of `>` with case-insensitive function
   [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)
4. Extract what falls in between starting and end point with
   [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

**BETTER WAY:**

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
[Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
```

- A HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ let you manipulate HTML in a very
  easy way!
- Require PHP 5+.
- Supports invalid HTML.
- Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.
- Extract contents from HTML in a single line.

Answer (score -3):

jQuery could do this for ya.

`$('img')[0]`

If it's in a smaller subsection of HTML within your page, then adjust the selector accordingly.

Comment: That's not very useful for a PHP app.