# What is the best way to get node value by using XPath API in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

What is the best way to get node value by using XPath API in C#?

```
<employee nric="S100" name="Mike" ... />
```

In T-SQL, the following will give the result:

```
select xml.value('(/employee/@nric)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `XmlDocument`:

```
        string s = "<employee nric=\"S100\" name=\"Mike\"  />";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(s);
        string value = doc.SelectSingleNode("//employee/@nric").Value;
```

Comment: . Thanks for your reply .. Do you have any idea on performance comparison between XmlDocument and XDocument?

Comment: For a small XML (less than a few MB) should not be much difference. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383919/xdocument-versus-xmldocument

Answer (score 0):

[Select Nodes Using XPath Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx.aspx) will be a good start.  Then [Xpath and selecting a single node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800/xpath-and-selecting-a-single-node)